# Maven scope provided

Tags: java, maven

Understand from the document, use of scope provided if you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. Question: How do I know the specific jar file is provided by JDK or container?

If I always use the default scope (compile), is there any different?

Sorry for my stupid question as I am new in java and maven.

Comment: Yes. It boils down to whether the dependency should be included in the output file. If you use *provided* it will not, and you are expected to know that you run it with a container that provides xyz logging framework (or that you will run it a classpath that includes xyz.jar to manage that dependency *externally*).

Answer (score 0):

You dont know that - it is up to you to decide whatever include given package (with scope `compile`) or given library will be available on classpath on runtime - that is what `provided` means

Comment: i'd just like to point out that for some things you _DEFINITELY KNOW_ youre not supposed to pack something - for example you dont pack J2EE API jars when deploying on J2EE containers (servlet API, java beans, those things). for those things packing your own copy of server-implemented APIs leads to runtime issues.